# Meaning and usage of "_embedded" in HATEOAS

Tags: json, spring, rest, hateoas, spring-hateoas

I'm using Spring Data REST, which supports HATEOAS. I'm new to this paradigm.

In `GET` responses from my RESTful web service I often receive results inside a node named `_embedded`.

I'm wondering: **what is `_embedded` node for? Is it part of REST specification? Or part of HATEOAS specification? Or is it specific for the Spring implementation of them?**

This is an example of JSON result for `GET http://localhost:8080/mywebservice/features`:

```
{
   "_links":
   {
       "search": { "href": "http://localhost:8080/mywebservice/features/search" }
   },
   "_embedded":
   {
       "features":
       [
           {
               "feature": "GROUND",
               "name": "Terreno",
               "data_type": "String",
               "_links":
               {
                   "self"  : { "href": "http://localhost:8080/mywebservice/features/GROUND" },
                   "values": { "href": "http://localhost:8080/mywebservice/features/GROUND }
               }
           },

           ...

       ]
   }
}
```

I noticed that I almost always have `_embedded` node in the response: if I request a collection, but even if a request a single resource by a search (for instance with `GET http://localhost:8080/mywebservice/persons/search/findByEmail?email=example@example@.com`).

I don't get `_embedded` node only if the request is for a specific resource, for instance when doing `GET http://localhost:8080/mywebservice/features/GROUND`.

Comment: According to the [HAL draft RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-08#section-4)
_`_embedded` contains embedded resources_

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There's neither a REST nor a HATEOAS specification. Both are only concepts, or architectural styles, if you will. `_embedded` is part of the [**HAL format**](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal#section-4.1.2).

It's intended to embed (sic!) resources where otherwise only their URIs would be returned. For example `GET http://localhost:8080/mywebservice/features` is supposed to only return a list of URIs, like `http://localhost:8080/mywebservice/features/GROUND`, and you would have to load every single `Feature` yourself if you needed it. By utilizing `_embedded` all `Feature` resources get embedded into the response so you don't have to load them separately.

Comment: And who, or what, controls the writting of the `_embeded` node in the response payload ?

Comment: `_embedded` is defined by the HAL spec. Spring Data REST assembles a `Resources` object based on its knowledge of the applications repositories and domain model, and then delegate actual serialization to Spring HATEOAS, a library built to render various forms of spec-based hypermedia.