# Getting JSONArray from RestTemplate.getForObject(...)

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've some Spring Boot applications (as microservices) each one with a Repository like:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "cart", path = "cart")
@CrossOrigin
public interface CartRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Cart, Long> {
```

When I save a "Cart" entity, a [@RepositoryEventHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/annotation/RepositoryEventHandler.html) class sends the entity as a json string to an Apache Kafka topic:

```
@HandleAfterCreate
public void handleAfterCreate(final Cart cart) throws JSONException, JsonProcessingException {
    final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(mapper.writeValueAsString(cart));
    json.put("eventType", "saved");
    sender.send(json.toString());
}
```

Finally, another Spring Boot application consumes the Kafka's topic.
Here, I get some related information by calling `RestTemplate.getForObject(...)` on other microserivces.

```
String templateURL="http://localhost:6060/api/cart/{id}/articles";
Map<String, Long> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("id", cartId);
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(templateURL, String.class, parameters);
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
```

The `obj` contains something like:

```
{"_embedded":{"articles":[{"id":1},{"id":2}]},"_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost:7074/api/cart/1/articles"}}}
```

But I can't find a way to get all the articles from that json.

I tried with:

```
Object articles = obj.get("articles");
```

But it doesn't work. I've already seen other answer like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468839/spring-data-rest-consume-list-of-entities-java-hateoas-client) or similar, but I can solve my problem.

So, how can I get a JSONArray from a RepositoryRestResource by RestTemplate?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you call get("_embedded") first, then get("articles")  ?

Comment: Yes of course, but I'm wondering if it's possible to avoid the "_embedded" node or what's the clearest way to read that data... anyway I think I will do it in that way. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this:  
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405637/meaning-and-usage-of-embedded-in-hateoas